# Searching for a single dash tag breaks tag formatting

Tags: bug, tags, design, search

Not sure what should be in the options text for [this search request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=a%20%5B-%5D), but definitely not this:

> [image: empty tag]

Also there is weird tag wiki shown on hover this area as said in comments:

> [image]

Comment: Wow, that tag wiki (shown on hover) is pretty messed up too.

Comment: yes..[tag_wiki/footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlQky.png)

Comment: @SurajRao nice. Can’t see it on my iPad without a mouse.